# coloured <a> tab by default

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs

i need to create a page which holds 3 tab-links at the top. Each tab-link has 2 states (either active or inactive), with a colour representing each state. 
On opening the page, the first tab-link should be highlighted as being active. When clicking other tab-links the colour on that first tab should change back to the default colour (inactive). I'm not sure how to go about it and don't seem to find the right answer.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs-headers">
        <li>
            <a href="">tab A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">tab B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">tab B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use jQuery/JavaScript, that's all I can help as you haven't tried

Answer (score 0):

In a css-File you can declare the look of your reflinks

```
a.tabmenu, a.tabmenu:visited, a.tabmenu:hover { color: blue }
a.tabmenu:active { color: yellow }
```

This should be what you want

```
<li>
    <a class="tabmenu" href="...">Tab A</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help my issue. The first tablink should be highlighted as active by default without needing to click on it.